# Bootstrap & jQuery Conflict

Tags: jquery, conflict, dropdown

I am using this following script in one of my page which slides a dropdown menu.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
<script>

                $('.hdr-toggle').click(function () {
                    $('.mobile-navigation').slideToggle();
                });

                $('a[href^="#"]').click(function () {
                    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:     $(this.hash).offset().top - 50}, 200);
                    return false;
                });

        </script>
```

bootstrap version 3.3.6. Dropdown slides perfectly fine, but some strange sort of conflict with bootstrap snipets. Tabs are not working. Carousel slider is working, indicators are working but next/previous button is not working. I have tried jquery no conflict, but that doesnt seems to make any change, i guess some # conflict there is which I cant figure what.

Please help.

Comment: Any errors thrown? Is jQuery.js being included in page more than once?

Comment: hard to help without a demo that replicates problem